# AngularJS 1.6.7 controller breakdown and refactor into components

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components

i'm having angularJS app where all controllers are in one file , i want break it down and seperate each controler then refactor it to component based as it's recommended for angularJS 1.5 and above. my current structure looks like this:

```
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function ($scope){
    //logic
}
])
```

and the same for all other controllers are in the same file "controllers.js", in my app.js i do:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', [
      'services',
      'controllers',
]);
```

what you advice to break down the controllers into components, thank you for answers and recommendations.

Comment: It's not necessarily "_recommended_", it's just makes it similar to Angular 2+. All your controllers will simply become isolated. It's best to **convert them into directives first**, because those are not that different from components. [Read more about conversion here](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/06/from-ngcontroller-to-components/)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, that's true it makes app easily maintainable , I will follow the tutorial, thanks for this awesome answer :)

Comment: I've seen this article. I've also refactored 5 or 6 angular apps from controllers to components. I see no advantage to going to directives first. It's an extra, sometimes more complicated step. There's also no need to use vm inside of component controllers. I think that article is suspect.

Comment: Also, there are few people writing about this migration. One that does, and does it well is Aviv Ben-Josef. I'd recommend his blog highly: http://www.codelord.net/. He actually has a book on this subject as well.

Comment: @MikeFeltman Thank you :) can you provide an insight for a better solution?

Comment: Basically, just go straight to components and skip the directives. The answer below is a great start. I'd also recommend Aviv's blog like I mentioned and honestly, if you're just getting started, I'm sure his book is well worth the $49. If you're using controllerAs syntax it literally shouldn't take you more than a few minutes per controller/template. If you have a lot of references to $scope it's a bit more difficult.

Comment: @MikeFeltman i'm using $scope and not even close to controllerAs syntax, since the all controllers are in one single file namely controllers.js like this: angular.module('controllers', ['commons'])

Answer (score 3):

Provided that you are using `$scope`, you could start by changing from scope to `controllerAs` syntax, that is, `$scope.foo = 'bar'` -> `<p>{{ foo }}</p>` would become `this.foo = 'bar'` -> `<p>{{ ctrl.foo }}</p>`.

#### controllerAs Syntax

From this:

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function ($scope){
    $scope.title = 'Home';
}]);
```

To this:

```
app.controller('HomeController', [function (){
    this.title = 'Home';
}]);
```

#### declaring components

Afterward, you'd be able to declare your components in two ways:

Partial refactor using the existing controller:

```
app.component('homeComponent', {
    controller: 'HomeController'
});
```

Or, full refactor replacing the controller:

```
app.component('homeComponent', {
    controller: [ function (){
        this.title = 'Home';
    }]
});
```

#### refactoring routers

Assuming that you are using `ui-router` (it's very similar to `ngRoute` so it wouldn't be a problem).

From this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
})
```

To this, for `ui-router 1.0+`:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    component: 'homeComponent'
  })
```

Or this, for older versions:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    template: '<home-component></home-component>'
  })
```

Ref.: [Guide: Route to Component](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component)

#### final thoughts

There's a pretty good [style guide for angularjs written by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) that you should have a look at and use what's worth for you. However, as it's been told by [@MikeFeltman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2528234) it's not accurate with angularjs 1.5 components application style practices; therefore, you should have a look at [Todd Motto's revised version](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide) of the guide including component application practices.

> **Disclaimer:** I see no point in converting a controller to a directive before making the component, you can declare the component directly because components are special directives and they carry a controller so it's convenient for you.

Comment: Go straight to ui-router 1.0+ if you can and route to component. It works wonderfully and has a super clean feel to it.

Comment: Thank you guys, now i have a problem with registering my controllers, since i'm using webpack, so i assume i should add the home.component.js to the list of all components which are bundled into one js file that called in index.html?

Comment: Also, John Papa's style guide was the bible, but last I looked he hasn't really kept it current since he moved to ng2. Todd Motto has revised his to reflect best practices for Angular 1.5 and later. https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide

Comment: @Lenilson de Castro Thank you for clear guide, i have a question what if i want to include a component inside a page rather than through route, for example i have search component i want to include in home.html?

Comment: @phpguy just write the component tag where you want to like: `<body><home-component></home-component></body>`

Comment: @MikeFeltman you're right, tod's guide is more up to date on angularjs 1.5+ features. I'll add a note on that. Thank you!

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro Thanks a lot :D i have issues when adding <home-component></home-component> i see the path to the html template only instead of controller login exceution

Comment: @phpguy you must use `templateUrl: 'home.html'` not `template: 'home.html'`

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro Thanks again, I have done that, still not working, see my code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/PayoZRazHCxkNssjCAYM?p=preview

Comment: @phpguy it's a bit difficult if you are not familiar with the technology, your code wasn't working because you weren't even able to create a basic setup of an angularjs  app, I suggest you to watch some basic tutorials before digging into the code otherwise won't even be able to get started. Here is your plunkr http://embed.plnkr.co/rQsihWVWARnmlTNWJn4t working with a simple basic setup. Also, I can't help you on this topic anymore because this has become way off topic, if you have different problems, please ask a new question.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro Appreciate it :) i can't simulate my  exact setup on plunkr. Once again thanks that really helped.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro i can't register my new components. is there a standard way to register them in app.js

Comment: @phpguy yes: `angular.module('myModule').component('myComponent', {})`

Comment: @phpguy create a new question describing and/or reproducing your problem and I see if I can help (or maybe someone else can).

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro Thank you, i did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281637/components-registration-and-structure-errors-angularjs