# components registration and structure errors AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to refactor my old AngularJS app for a better structure, first, i'm breaking down controllers to components , I'm following this syntax, but get error failed to instantiate module, and component not registered. my component looks like:

```
 angular.module('app')
  .component('LoginComponent', {})
  .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', function ($scope,) {  }]);
```

and in my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngMaterial',
  'LoginComponent' 
]);
```

in my webpack:

```
  module.exports = {
    entry: ['path/login.component.js',
    ],
};
```

Comment: You don't inject component as module dependency...you only inject other modules

Comment: @charlietfl is correct, I think what you are trying to achieve is to have a components module, which is more angular 2+ alike. Therefore, you'd have to create a separated module, say `componentsModule`, and inject it in your `app` module as dependency module.

Comment: @charlietfl I inject the component as a module dependency in app.js after ngMaterial. i get this error:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: But the component is not a module. It is registered to the module when you call  `angular.module('app')
  .component('LoginComponent', function()..`.

Comment: @charlietfl so i have to register it in my app.js as well, can you provide a demo?

Comment: NO ! .... that is what the call to `component()` is for

Comment: @phpguy you lack too much knowledge on how angularjs works my dear, it'll make your job really hard. Check this guide out https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module, it's about angularjs' module system, you'll understand it better how things get registered on a module and the module gets imported into another module so that this module can access things that you've registered on that module.

Comment: For example, `ngMaterial` has a bunch of `COMPONENT`, `DIRECTIVE`, `CONTROLLER` and `FILTER` registered on it, so that you can import the `MODULE` into you app `MODULE` and use material's `COMPONENTS`.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro Thank you for clarification, i got it to work now

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro i'm refactoring my old controller, how do i make changes accordingly, my new structure is which based on es6 `class LoginController {
  constructor() { //logic } }`
does the controller dependencies go inside the constrcutor?
`.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', 'service', '$mdDialog',, '$window', function ($scope, $mdDialog, $window) {  `